# Is there any counter example for $\sum\limits_{d|(m, 2n), d\neq 1, 2}\varphi(d)=\sum\limits_{d|(m,n)}\varphi(d)$ or is it true?

Tags: number-theory

Respected all.

The following problem I got stick although elementary but I am unable to finish it through logical argument.

Question is: If $m, n \in \mathbb N$ then $\sum\limits_{d|(m, 2n), d\neq 1, 2}\varphi(d)$ is same as $\sum\limits_{d|(m,n)}\varphi(d)$. How to establish it ? Is it true in general or there is any counter example for it ?

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: Well, what if $(m,n)=(m,2n)$?

Comment: OMG. Even that  is also required !!

Comment: So I think, we need to establish if $(m, 2n)-2=(m,n)$ or not. Am I right ?

Comment: Recall that $\sum\limits_{d\mid N}\varphi(d) = N$.

Comment: @lhf but then LHS becomes $(4, 4)-1-1=2$ and RHS as $(4, 2)=2$. Am I making any mistake ?

Comment: @Anjan3, right, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comment, we only need to ask wether $(m,2n)-2=(m,n)$ holds or not. Write $D:=(m,n)$. Since $D$ is a common divisor to $m$ and $2n$ we can find an integer $l$ such that :

$$(m,2n)=Dl $$

The equation becomes :

$$D(l-1)=2 $$

But $l$ cannot be anything else than $2$ or $1$, hence $l$ is necessarily $2$ if the above equation holds. This implies that $D=2$. On the other hand it is easily seen that if $D=2$ and $l=2$ then the above equation holds. I think that the set of solution is :

$$(2^{k}m',2n')\text{ where } m' \text{ and }  n' \text{ are odd and prime to each other and } k\geq 2 $$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{1\le d\mid m}\varphi(d)=m$ for any $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ (3 proofs [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373551/prove-that-sum-dn-phid-n-where-phi-is-the-eulers-phi-function-n-c)).

The equation is equivalent to $(m,2n)-2=(m,n)$.

Define $\upsilon_2(a)=t\iff (2^t\mid a,\, 2^{t+1}\nmid a)$.

$(m,2n)>(m,2n)-2=(m,n)$ and $2$ is prime,

so we must have $(m,2n)=2(m,n)$ and $\upsilon_2(m)>\upsilon_2(n)$, i.e.

$(m,2n)-2=(m,n)\implies ((m,n)=2,\, \upsilon_2(m)>\upsilon_2(n))$.

$\iff (m=4k,\, n=2n_1$ with $(k,n_1)=1$, $\,n_1$ odd$)$,

which is indeed a solution.