# Divisibility property of the totient function $\varphi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, totient-function

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{d \vert n} \varphi(d)= n
\end{equation}

where $\varphi$ is the totient function of Euler.

Comment: see also (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1373551)

Comment: You can have many www proofs of this result, using the keyword "totient function" as you know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $d\vert n$, let $\mathcal{O}_d$ be the sets of elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Using Lagrange's theorem, $\{\mathcal{O}_d\}_{d\vert n}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Howeover, as an element of order $d$ spans a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$, $\mathcal{O}_d$ has cardinality $\varphi(d)$.