# A finite abelian group $A$ is cyclic iff for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\#\{a \in A : na = 0\}\le n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

> Let $A$ be a finite abelian group. Prove that $A$ is cyclic iff for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$
> $$\#\{a \in A : na = 0\}\le n.$$

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I don't think that this is true for finitely generated abelian groups. Take $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$, for instance. Then the given set has cardinality $1$ for any $n$, but the group is not cyclic.

Comment: thank you. It is Finite abelian group , not finitely generated. I'm editing the  question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment section by [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15500/arthur), your statement is partially false. Let us show your statement for finite abelian groups.

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, then there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(d_i)_{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}\in{\mathbb{N}_{\geqslant 2}}^n$ such that: $$\forall i\in\{2,\ldots,n\},d_{i-1}\vert d_i\textrm{ and }G\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^n\mathbb{Z}/(d_i).$$

- Assume that for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $|\{g\in G\textrm{ s.t. }mg=0\}|\leqslant m$. One has to show that $n\in\{0,1\}$. Assume by contradiction that $n\geqslant 2$, let us take $m:=d_2$ and notice that for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}/(d_1)\oplus\mathbb{Z}/(d_2)$, one has: $$m(x,y,0,\ldots,0)=0.$$
  Which is a contradiction, since we have found $d_1d_2>m$ elements in $\{g\in G\textrm{ s.t. }mg=0\}$.
- Assume that $G$ is cyclic, since $G$ is finite, $G\cong\mathbb{Z}/(|G|)$ and I let you show that the given condition holds.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proof that appears in Weil's gem *Number theory for beginners* and in several other books.

Let $m$ be the order of $A$ and 
let $\psi(n)$ be the number of elements of order $n$ in $A$.

Then, by Lagrange's theorem, $m=\sum_{d\mid m} \psi(d)$ because every element has an order that is a divisor of $m$.

If $\psi(d)>0$, then there is an element of order $d$ and the subgroup generated by it has order $d$ and so the hypothesis on $A$ implies that $\psi(d) = \phi(d)$.

Therefore, for all $d \mid m$, we have $\phi(d) \ge \psi(d)$.

Now $m = \sum_{d\mid m} \phi(d) \ge \sum_{d\mid m} \psi(d) = m$. (*)

This means that $\psi(d)=\phi(d)$ for all $d \mid m$.

In particular, $\psi(m)>0$, which means that $A$ has an element of order $m$ and so is cyclic.

(*) The first equality comes from counting the fractions $1/m,\dots,m/m$ when they are reduced.

Comment: This proof does not assume that $A$ is abelian.

Comment: In the fourth paragraph, why say the hypothesis implies that $\psi(d)=\phi(d)$ please?

Comment: @Benny, if $g$ has order $d$ then the hypothesis on $A$ imply that $\{a \in A : a^d = 1\} = \langle g \rangle$, which has $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the (*)? I neither understood how you got that from counting the fractions nor why you counted the fractions.

Comment: @StarPlatinumZAWARUDO, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194713/589