# Finite non-abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The other day I was reading *Topics in Algebra* by I.N.Herstein and found a problem which can be summarised as -

> Show that any two non-abelian groups of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes with $p>q$, are isomorphic.

### My strategy

there exists a subgroup of order $p$ and $q$ out of which the $p$-group is a normal group by using the fact that

> there exists a homomorphism $\alpha:G\to S_q$ such that the kernel is contained in the $p$-group.

As $p$ and $q$ are cyclic let their generator be $a$ and $b$ respectively. As $\langle a\rangle \cap\langle b\rangle=\phi$ then $\forall g\in G$ $g=a^ib^j$. As $\langle a\rangle $ is normal $bab^{-1}=a^k \implies b^iab^{-i}=a^{k^i} \implies k^q \equiv 1\pmod{p})$ , $k\neq1 $ as it is non-abelian group. Let the two groups be $G_1$ and $G_2$. Let $a_1$ and $b_1$ are the generators of $p$-group and $q$-group respectively and similarly $a_2$ and $b_2$ for $G_2$. Let $$b_1a_1b_1^{-1}=a_1^{k_1}$$ $$b_2a_2b_2^{-1}=a_2^{k_2}$$ If I use the fact that $\Bbb Z_p$ multiplicative group is cyclic, then there exists $n\in N$ $,n\le q-1$ such  that $[k_2]^n=[k_1] $ and  $[k_1],[k_2] \in \Bbb Z_p$.
hence $\beta :G_1 \to G_2$ , $\beta(a_1)=a_2$ and $\beta(b_1)=b_2^n$ is an isomorphism. But the fact that $\Bbb Z_p$ multiplicative group is cyclic is not done in the previous parts. So, I am asking for a proof without using the fact that $\Bbb Z_p$ multiplicative group is cyclic.

Comment: Your use of $\LaTeX$ here was, quite frankly, bizarre; please take note of my edit for future reference and check out [this MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks for your support.

Comment: But it is (almost) trivial that $\Bbb Z_p^{\times}\cong \Bbb Z_{p-1}$, see for example [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988847/is-it-possible-to-prove-that-up-for-prime-p-is-cyclic-using-only-group-t).

Comment: Try to use Cayley's theorem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I would not describe that as trivial! I remember, in my undergraduate days (long ago), I tried to prove that myself as an exercise and failed. I was annoyed with myself when I saw the solution, because  I was familiar with all of the ingredients of the proof.

Comment: If by mistake I keep posting duplicate questions would I reach my limit for asking questions?

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, I agree. It is not really trivial if you haven't seen it. However, someone asking about groups of order $pq$ probably should have seen the fact that $U(p)$ is cyclic. It doesn't seem reasonable to me that one tries to avoid this for this exercise.

Comment: @Charliecharles No, there is no such limit.