# Show that $n$ is square-free if and only if the sum over all divisors of $\mu(d)^2\varphi(d)$ is $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $n$ is square-free if and only if $\sum _{d\mid n} \mu (d)^2\varphi (d) = n$.

Attempt:

The only non-zero terms in the sum are the terms where $d = p_{i_1}\cdots p_{i_l}$ where $p_{i_1},\cdots ,p_{i_l}$ are distinct primes.

Then the sum becomes $\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)$ where $d = p_{i_1}\cdots p_{i_l}$.

Now is there a way to show that this sum equals $n$?

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194705/is-there-a-direct-elementary-proof-of-n-sum-kn-phik)

Comment: There are two things to prove: (i) If $n$ is square-free then the sum is $n$ and (ii) if the sum is $n$ then $n$ is square-free. It is best to prove these separately. For the first, there are many proofs. Maybe most mechanical, if you already have the result, is to use the fact that $\sum_{d\mid n} \varphi(d)$ is multiplicative.

Comment: If $n$ is a perfect square or a multiple of a perfect square, then at least one $\mu(d)^2 = 0$, and hence $\mu(d)^2 \phi(d) = 0$. If $n = p^2$ (where $p$ is some positive prime), then $\mu(p)^2 \phi(p) = p - 1$, and the whole sum is $p$, which clearly falls short of $p^2$. Also note that squaring the Möbius function is essentially the same as taking its absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the trouble to typeset this in mathematical notation
we have that

$$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)^2 \phi(d)
= \sum_{S\subseteq Q} \prod_{p\in S} (p-1).$$

where $Q$ is the set of prime factors of $n.$
This equals

$$\left.\prod_{p\in Q} (1+(p-1)x)\right|_{x=1}$$

by the combinatorial subset construction.

Simplifying we get
$$\prod_{p\in Q} p.$$

So the  function in question is  the product of the  prime divisors of
$n.$

Now for the foreward direction obviously if $n$ is squarefree then
$\prod_{p\in Q} p  = n.$ On the  other hand if $\prod_{p\in Q}  p = n$
then $n$ must  be squarefree because if it  isn't we have $\prod_{p\in
Q} p \lt n,$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to record an alternative solution.

Note that 
$$\sum_{d\mid n} \varphi(d) =n,$$ and $\mu(d)^2$ is either 0 or 1, so 
$$\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d)^2\varphi(d) =n$$
if and only if for no $d\mid n$ we have $\mu(d)=0$. This is true if and only if no divisor $d$ of $n$ is divisible by the square of a prime if and only if all divisors of $n$ are square-free. Lastly, this is true if and only if $n$ is square-free.

Hence $$\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d)^2\varphi(d) =n$$
if and only if $n$ is square-free as desired.