# Proving This Summation Using Euler's Totient Theorem

Tags: number-theory

I Recently Learnt about Euler's Totient Theorem where
$$
a^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod n
$$
Now I Am Stuck When Im Supposed To Prove The Following Summation
$$
n = \sum_{d|n}^{}\phi(d)
$$
So I Needed Some **Hints** To Prove The Following Summation. Majorly I'm Not Able To Understand what does $d|n$ means in the summation.

Comment: The notation $d\,|\,n$ means that the sum is taken over the (positive) divisors of $n$.  Note too that your first congruence only holds if $\gcd(a,n)=1$.  That sort of detail is important, don't ignore it.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194705/is-there-a-direct-elementary-proof-of-n-sum-kn-phik) is another duplicate.